# How to return single string value from flask to Html label tag?

Tags: python, flask, data-binding

I am trying to interact with my machine learning model where I can get the input value to the flask route method from HTML but not able to pass on the response with a string value to the ajax query.

THe click of the button hits the ajax function and does goto the flask route function, but it doesn't even hit the success or error part of the ajax function.
Gives 405 Method not Allowed error.
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2020 13:15:17] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -

I am new to Flask and not aware of data binding options. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML PART

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', 
     filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
           <title>Twitter Sarcasm Detection</title>
    <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script> 
    <script src="static/js/signUp.js"></script>
    <style>
    h1 {
        margin-top: 13rem;
        color: chocolate
    }
    p{
        margin-top: 36px;
    }
    .form-group{
        margin: 3rem !important;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
<div class="container" style="text-align:center">
<h1>Twitter Sarcasm Detection</h1>
<p>Enter the text below to find out if its Sarcastic or not!</p>
<form action="http://localhost:5000/" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userText" name="userText">
    </div>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label id="prediction" name="prediction"></label>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

AJAX query in the script file

```
    $(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/predictSarcasm',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                    $('#prediction').val(response.result);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

FLASK Code

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, json
from joblib import load

pipeline = load("text_classification.joblib")

def requestResults(text):
    tweet = pipeline.predict([text])
    if tweet == 0:
        return "Not-Sarcastic"
    else:
        return "Sarcastic"

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('Index.html')
    
@app.route('/predictSarcasm', methods=['POST'])
def predictSarcasm():
    text = request.form['userText']
    prediction = requestResults(text)
    return json.dumps({'status':'OK','result':str(prediction)});

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use forms for ajax

Html Code

```
<h1>Twitter Sarcasm Detection</h1>
<p>Enter the text below to find out if its Sarcastic or not!</p>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userText" name="userText">
    </div>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label id="prediction" name="prediction"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ajax Code

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/predictSarcasm',
            contentType: "application/json",
           data: JSON.stringify({ "text": $('#userText').val()})
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                    $('#prediction').val(response.result);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
        });
    });
```

Python Code

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/predictSarcasm', methods=['POST'])
def predictSarcasm():
    json= request.get_json()
    text=json["text"]
    prediction = requestResults(text)
    return jsonify({"status":"OK",'result':str(prediction)})
```